# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < for JavaScript files

Tags: node.js, angular, express, mean-stack

I am developing a MEAN stack CRUD project . After build my project I am getting this error from index.html file in `dist/ngAppVideos/index.html` folder.i tried `<base href="/">` but no luck.
This is my index.html file

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">

<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">

<title>NgAppVideos</title>

<base href="/ngAppVideos/">

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">

</head>

<body>

<app-root></app-root>

<script type="text/javascript" src="runtime.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="styles.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

This is server.js file

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');
const api = require('./server/routes/api');

const port = 3000;

const app = express();

api.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));


app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));


app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use('/api', api);


app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/ngAppVideos/index.html'));
});

app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log("Server running on localhost:" + port);
});
```

I tried many ways like modifying base-href location in index.html file but didn't work

in my server.js I changed my `__dirname` to `dist/index.html` but this time it just prompt `No such directory can be found..`error.

Thanks!

Comment: When using code in a question, please put all code into code blocks: usually, indent all code lines by 4 spaces (preferable), but for inline code on the same line as non-code, surround the code with backticks (`\``).

Comment: Try using just `<script... ` instead of `<script type="text/javascript"...` If that doesn't work you could put it in a codepen for us to try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a few mistakes:

1)for set public file to `dist` must be set the full path of `dist`.maybe is there in a subdirectory or anything like this.

2)in your node.js code, you tell return all `GET` request by an HTML file and in front-end code, you get a javascript file but your server code sends an HTML file and front-end wait for javascript code but get HTML file and send you this error.

to solving these problems must be set a correct public folder and put your javascript file to it and change get javascript path in front, for example

set public like this:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'subdirectory/dist')))
```

and change script tag to:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/runtime.js"></script>
```

don't forget put your javascript file in `dist` folder